# Como seleccionar un solo checkbox React

Tags: reactjs, checkbox

Necesito seleccionar un solo checkbox ,pero no lo he logrado aun

```
return (
<InputGroup className="mb-3">
  <InputGroup.Text>{props.answer}</InputGroup.Text>
  <InputGroup.Checkbox
    id="OneChekbox "
    type="radio"
    onChange={onChangeHandler}
    aria-label="Checkbox for following text input"
  />
</InputGroup>
```

);

estaba pensando en un condicional o algo usar un Disabled ,pero no supe como hacerlo

Agradezco de antemano

Comment: Los checkbox tienen seleccion multiple. Para una opcion podrias usar radios

Comment: Lo intente pero tampo me da

Comment: Aqui tienes un buen tutorial sobre todos los elementos de formulario en react https://youtu.be/ECWR2ohHWKc